# Does Python have a basename function that is equal to Unix basename?

Tags: python

```
>>> os.path.basename("../dir/")
''
$ basename ../dir/
dir
```

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

> `os.path.basename(path)`
>
> Return the base name of pathname *path*. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing *path* to the function `split()`. Note that the result of **this function is different from the Unix basename program;** where **basename** for `'/foo/bar/'` returns `'bar'`, the `basename()` function returns an empty string (`''`).

Is there a function that isn't different from Unix basename?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in one function, AFAIK, but it is not difficult. Just remove the trailing slash first:

```
os.path.basename(os.path.normpath("../dir/"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `pathlib.Path`'s [name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) attribute is what you want.

```
from pathlib import Path

pa = Path('/foo/bar/zoom')
print(f"{pa.name=}")
pa = Path('/foo/bar/')
print(f"{pa.name=}")
```

Output (to which I've added the macOS `basename`):

```
(venv38) me@explore$ python test.py
pa.name='zoom'
pa.name='bar'
(venv38) me@explore$ basename '/foo/bar/zoom'
zoom
(venv38) me@explore$ basename /foo/bar/
bar
```

Comment: ah, good catch.  `basename /foo/bar/` in bash.  but output remains same, phhhew.  Interesting btw that bash does not care about the file not existing, it really evaluates these as strings *for this purpose*.

Comment: It's not just Bash, it's any implementation of basename, cause you might be dealing with filenames that don't exist locally, for example if they're from a remote system or if they're to-be-created.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `basename` has a feature whereby `basename /path/to/file.ext .ext` returns just `file`. If you need both features, look for

```
os.path.splitext(os.path.os.path.basename(path))[0]
```

or, with `pathlib`,

```
pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path(path).name).stem
```

The .splitext method and the `.stem` attribute remove anything after the last dot, or nothing if the basename does not contain a dot.